# Opening image files for load_sift in scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

[The documentation for load_sift](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.load_sift)

`from skimage import io
img = open('g.png')
rv = io.load_sift(img)`

This code is not working. It seems that this is not how I'm supposed to open the image file.I could not understand the documentation.

Comment: That function is very bad written and the documentation is almost inexistent. I recommend you to look for alternatives...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, @Jalo: the docstring clearly states that the function reads SIFT files, and where those files come from (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.load_sift).

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Have you tried using your method below with any sample image and afterwards apply the load_sift() function of the OP? Because I did and it raises an coding error. Actually, I initially thought that the problem was the same that you mention below and tried a similar solution.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Moreover, the docstring does not "clearly states that the function reads SIFT files". It literally states that it reads a  **string or open file**. I have been looking at the source code and for my it is very error prone, reason why I sad it was bad written

Comment: I hope the expanded answer provides more clarity; let me know.

Comment: Also, please help us to make it better!  We would be so happy to receive your pull requests.

Answer (score 4):

The `load_sift` routine is not meant for operating on numpy arrays or image files.  As the `f` parameter is documented, it states:

```
Input file generated by the feature detectors from
http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/ or
http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/
```

I.e., these are specially formatted files with the SIFT features already extracted by the binaries found at those URLs.  The reason we do not calculate SIFT features inside scikit-image is because those routines are patent encumbered, therefore you have to use an external utility or library to calculate them.

In scikit-image, you read in images as follows:

```
from skimage import io
image = io.imread('g.png')
```

This returns a numpy array, that you can manipulate any way you wish.  To additionally extract SIFT features:

1. Download the external binary
2. Run it on your images
3. Load the resulting file with `load_sift`

Because there was uncertainty about the docstring, I have [made a patch](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/2404/files) to clarify that an external tool is needed.

Comment: As @Jalo mentioned, this does not work with the load_sift() function.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to address the above comments.

Comment: It is clear for me now ;) However, I would also add to the first docstring line that the input file is required to have a special format...

Comment: I've updated the docstring in the patch as you suggested, @Jalo